# Excel pivot/group/transpose

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2019

Data presented like this (3 rows with same key 1,2 etc):

```
k va  vb
1 A11 B11
1 A12 B12
1 A13 B13
2 A21 B21
2 A22 B22
2 A23 B23
...
```

I need to group and transpose each group so I get (dont need keys even)

```
va1 vb1 va2 vb2 va3 vb3
A11 B11 A12 B12 A13 B13
A21 B21 A22 B22 A23 B23
...
```

Comment: You could use something like: `=INDEX($B$2:$C$7,(ROWS($A$1:$A1)-1)*3+(COLUMNS($A$1:A$1)-1)/2+1,2-MOD(COLUMNS($A$1:A$1),2))` - adjust the first range to match your actual data set.

Comment: it only shows 2 rows ok but the rest are !REFs. there are 6565 rows not just 2

Comment: @BoppityBop you will need to adjust the `$B$2:$C$7` to your dataset size.

Comment: my bad. it works. please write as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$C$7,(ROWS($A$1:$A1)-1)*3+(COLUMNS($A$1:A$1)-1)/2+1,2-MOD(COLUMNS($A$1:A$1),2))
```

Adjust the first range (the $B$2:$C$7 part) to match your actual data set